# Brackets, no extensions available?

Tags: ide, adobe-brackets

I just have fresh installed Brackets from snap (default ubuntu application store). Now, I'm waiting since 15 minutes to see anything in the Extensions Manager. Nothing except the same animated logo is visible in the "available", "installed" and other tabs. Is this a normal behaviour?

Sadly, I am also not able to install the same app from dep package, because it looks like there is no "libcurl3" package available (libcurl3-nss, libcurl3-gnutls is not recognized as a proper dependency for Brackets)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVHmW.jpg

I just have foud "cprov-brackets" available to install with snap. It does have the same problem. Is there a problem with snap, which may have problems  connecting to remote server?

edit:
Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, 3 days ago upgraded from 18.04 LTS, updated with the most recent updates. Brackets version 1.14.1

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm going to answer myself. As the snap version of Brackets available in Ubuntu 20.04 seems to be slightly broken (and outdated), I have tried to install Brackets from deb package. The only problem is, the most recent deb version available this day, requires libcurl3. Ubuntu 20.04 is equipped with libcurl4, so downgrading seems not clever.

In the discussion here https://dev.to/jake/using-libcurl3-and-libcurl4-on-ubuntu-1804-bionic-184g, a nice solution was provided. Following the steps proposed by mr. Thomas (https://dev.to/lin4fun), it is possible to change the package dependency from libcurl3 to libcurl4. Here are the steps:

- Download the .deb installer file
- Inside the folder your downloaded the file run `dpkg-deb -R ./Brackets.Release.1.xx.64-bit.deb Brackets`
- Edit file **Brackets/DEBIAN/control** and replace `libcurl3` with `libcurl4`
- Rebuild .deb installer running `dpkg-deb -b Brackets Brackets-fixed.deb`
- Install Brackets using the fixed installer running `sudo dpkg -i Brackets-fixed.deb`

As for me, it looks like the "fixed" version of Brackets is working fine. Extension manager is working as expected, the left, file panel is visisble. I hope, any unexpected, not backward compatible libcurl function won't destroy my happiness now.  At least, for my small, local jobs, Brackets seems to work fine now.